# How does 2 java classes that depend on each other compiles?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes ChatServer and ChatServerThread

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{
    private ServerSocket     server = null;
    private Thread           thread = null;
    private ChatServerThread client = null;
}
```

and

```
public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
{
    private ChatServer       server    = null;
    private Socket           socket    = null;
    private int              ID        = -1;
    private DataInputStream  streamIn  =  null;
    private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
}
```

How would these compile? If I want to write a build script which class would you compile first?

Comment: Put them in the same compile and there won't be any problem.  Circular dependencies are not an issue.

Comment: Conceptually, the compiler makes two passes over each Java source file, the first pass to extract the external definitions (equivalent to an "include file") that are needed by other classes, the second pass to actually compile things and create the `.class` file.

Comment: @HotLicks -- post as an answer?

Comment: @HotLicks If you can post an answer I can mark it as accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, the compiler makes two passes over each Java source file, the first pass to extract the external definitions (equivalent to an "include file") that are needed by other classes, the second pass to actually compile things and create the .class file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. The compiler will compile both co-dependent classes either way.

**But** in fact your `ChatServer` should not have a `ChatServerThread` member at all, unless you're planning on only having one client in the chat.